# Is there a function to get process via bpf_trace?

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

Context: I am trying to trace packet of a particular port and redirect it but for a particular process. Right now it traces throughout the interface.

```
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "filter"
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>

int udpfilter(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
  bpf_trace_printk("got a packet\n");
  void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
  void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
  struct ethhdr *eth = data;
  if ((void*)eth + sizeof(*eth) <= data_end) {
    struct iphdr *ip = data + sizeof(*eth);
    if ((void*)ip + sizeof(*ip) <= data_end) {
      if (ip->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
        struct udphdr *udp = (void*)ip + sizeof(*ip);
        if ((void*)udp + sizeof(*udp) <= data_end) {
          if (udp->dest == ntohs(7999)) {
            bpf_trace_printk("udp port 7999\n");
            udp->dest = ntohs(7998);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Output I am getting

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo python3 main.py
/virtual/main.c:1:9: warning: 'KBUILD_MODNAME' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "filter"
        ^
<command line>:3:9: note: previous definition is here
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "bcc"
        ^
1 warning generated.
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2564.611068: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2564.611082: 0: udp port 7999'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2564.611090: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2564.611093: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2564.611094: 0: udp port 7999'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2564.611095: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2565.611593: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2565.611605: 0: udp port 7999'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2565.611618: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2566.612184: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2566.612195: 0: udp port 7999'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2566.612207: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2567.611801: 0: got packet'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2567.611812: 0: udp port 7999'
b'              nc-1508    [000] ..s1  2567.611825: 0: got packet'
```

Is there any function to grep out the `nc` and if udp port 7999 is traced I can use XDP_DROP to drop the packet.

Something like this
if process == nc && udp->dest == ntohs(7999)
XDP_DROP

Answer (score 1):

The process information is not reliable in XDP programs. It's often just the PID of the process that got interrupted to treat received packets, so it could end up being anything. If you add a bit of load on the receiving server, you'll probably notice that all sorts of userspace processes are reported in place of `nc`.

Comment: So the information is not reliable? How do I fetch PID of the process, I tried ```bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();``` but spits out an error ```unknown bpf..```
I am trying ```xdp_drop``` application specific packet

Comment: There is no way to get the destination process for a packet at the XDP hook because that information is simply not computed yet at that point.